# Is it possible to have a Case Statement in SQL Server Computed Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with two date columns, both allow nulls.

if FileDate is not null then AsOfDate needs to equal (FileDate - Offset) where Offset is a integer column with a default of zero.

Here is my table def:

```
CREATE TABLE [import].[CMAR_GLXXXX](
[FileDate] [date] NULL,
[LoadDTM] [date] NULL,
[AsOfDate] [date] NULL,
[AccountNumber] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[CostCenter] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[OffSet] [int] default (0) NOT NULL,
[Value] [decimal](10,2) NOT NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I tried using the following:

```
(case when [File] IS NULL then NULL else dateadd(day,(-1 * [Offset]),[FileDate]) end)
```

Unfortunately the computed column error dialog doesn't display much help in troubleshooting the expression.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your full `create table` statement please?

Comment: Will do but col names are different.  I'll clean up the question so they match.

Comment: `CASE` is not a statement - it's an **expression** (like `a+b`) which can return one atomic value (from a set of possible alternatives). And yes - a `CASE` expression can be used anywhere where any other expression can be used - including in a computed column definition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A case expression is perfectly valid here but not needed for your desired output. Let sql server handle NULLS naturally.

```
dateadd(day,(-1 * x),[d1])
```

--EDIT--

To demonstrate here is a table definition. Seems this does exactly what you are looking for.

```
create table #Something
(
    x int
    , d1 datetime
    , compCol as dateadd(day, (-1 * x), [d1])
)

insert #Something
select 3, null union all
select 4, '2016-01-01'

select *
from #Something
```

Comment: Thanks SL - the follow now works with my table: case filedate when null then null else dateadd(dd,-1*offset,filedate) end

Comment: ... and yes - there is no need for the case statement in my scenario.  The following works fine:  dateadd(dd,-1*offset,filedate)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your expression is correct. just use correct syntax for case.

```
CREATE TABLE CMAR_GLXXXX(
[FileDate] [date] NULL,
[LoadDTM] [date] NULL,
[AsOfDate] [date] NULL,
[AccountNumber] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[CostCenter] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[OffSet] [int] default (0) NOT NULL,
[Value] [decimal](10,2) NOT NULL
 )

 select 
 (case when [FileDate] IS NULL then NULL else dateadd(day,(-1 * [OffSet]),[FileDate]) end) 
 from CMAR_GLXXXX
```